# my.settings.upgrade not working! VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to run the update settings taking them from the previous version of the program, the problem is that it does not work.

I have created a field "ser" which is set to true by default, so that every time an update is made the field "ser" becomes false, in particular:

```
 If My.Settings.ser = "True" Then
    My.Settings.Upgrade () 
    My.Settings.ser = False 
    My.Settings.Save () 
 end If
```

This should work well, it must be said that this code is executed within the form load and not in a function, it is placed first. 
I read in the network that the cause of why not update, it could be that the settings are part of an other version and not a equal, 
consequently this conflict is created that does not allow the update. I wonder how I could resolve this situation as they are really in trouble.

Comment: What is the exact error wording that pops up?

Comment: I think upgrade works in unison with the version number; you didnt mention anything about that

Comment: I have only one number versione: 1.0.0 but in the folder appdata/local/application name, i have this folder: applicationStrongName.exe and applicationnameUrl, this is the downliaded versione.. Is strange..